# Перенос сайта на локальный компютер, проблема с Денвером

Tags: modx, denwer

Здраствуйте. Помогите вот в каком деле. Я скопировал сайт в директорию C:\WebServers\home\localhost\www\сайт
 создал БД таку как на хостинге, в файле config.inc.php поменял настройки для ловкального сервера, теперь захожу 
 http://localhost/сайт/ пишет "Error 503 Site temporarily unavailable". Что делать в таком случии? 
 Я находил статьи про то что нужно установить modx, я скачал modx взял файл setup скопировал в свою директорию потом пробовал запустить и обновить просто но у меня не находит директории \home\сайт . Хз что за бред и как с ним боротся. Потому огромна прозьба помочь разобратся с єтим. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите в первую очередь, что в логах пишет Ваш сервер.
И посмотрите здесь: [Отчего возникает ошибка 503 (Service Temporarily Unavailable)](http://www.jino.ru/support/faq/problems/error-503.html#error-503).